Gas burners not giving out same gas all around the burner
I have a russell hob 4 ring burner,which im using with propane gas bottle.
I use the largest ring mostly. This ring is not giving out the same amount of gas all the way around it. This means food is getting burnt on one side.
Can you help.

This burner appears to be set up for natural gas. Has it been properly adapted for propane gas?

describe the flame ... do not make assumptions  about amounts of gas

Have you just cleaned the burners? Or are they dirty? If something (water drop, food gunk, etc) blocks one of the series of holes in the burner where the gas comes out to be burned, that blockage can prevent the fire from jumping past and lighting the next hole in the series, thus not allowing all the holes to light up. Had that happen several times on my gas stoves over the years. A good clean and dry was necessary.

Yes i have always kept the burner clean,still not working. I wonder if the problem is with the pipe that sends gas to this one burner.

Have you removed it and cleaned the inside of it as well? The pipe leading to the burner won't cause uneven flame, as it supplies the gas to the burner, where it's distributed. The distribution in the burner is uneven, from your problem description, and that means there's some sort of partial blockage (food, spiderwebs, whatever) between the gas pipe entering the burner and the holes on the edge of the burner, or in (some of) the holes on the edge of the burner.
